# Law of Large Numbers and Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

Let ${X_i}$ be a sequence of random variables which follows the Bernoulli distribution with $Bernoulli(\frac1i)$, for each $i = 1,...,n$. In other words, $P(X_i=1) = \frac 1i$ and $P(X_i=0) = 1 - \frac 1i$ for each $i = 1,...,n$. Show that $X_n$ tends in probability to $0$.

I have no idea how to even get started on this, so any tips would help greatly.

My lecturer has just covered the Law of Large Numbers, convergence in probability and what makes a good estimator (unbiased, efficient and consistent) but I think I speak for the whole class when I say that we understood little of what she was teaching.

***EDIT***

I would first like to thank the kind souls who gave me hints on how I should go about solving this and also vetting what I had come up with.

This is my answer:

To show $X_n \to 0$, we should aim to show $P(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon) = 0$ for any positive $\epsilon$. Then, since $X_n$ follows a Bernoulli Distribution, so $X_n$ can only take on non-negative integer values. Thus, $P(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon) = P(X_n > \epsilon)$. Now, I make use of Markov's Inequality, so $P(X_n  > \epsilon) \leqslant \frac 1\epsilon E(X_n) = \frac 1\epsilon \frac 1n$. As $n \to \infty$, $\frac 1n \to 0$, so $P(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon) = 0$ and we can conclude that $X_n$ tends in probability to $0$.

Any further comments on how I can improve this answer are welcome :) or if anyone has any other more elegant ways to answer the question, they are welcome too!

Comment: I can say as a graduate in statistics that I have never heard of "convergence in probability". That's said, a bit of googling and wikipedia-ing and I found my way. Once you have the definition it becomes a question of analysis, in which case, can you do it yourself? If not, rewrite your question and we can help.

Comment: Hmm. Okay well this is how my lecturer described "convergence in probability" - for any positive $\epsilon$, the probability that $Z_n$ differs from $c$ by more than $\epsilon$ will eventually decrease to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint, follow through your comment where you said

> this is how my lecturer described "convergence in probability" - for any positive $ϵ$, the probability that $Z_n$ differs from $c$ by more than $ϵ$ will eventually decrease to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

In this case $c=0$ and $Z_n=X_n$. So

- For any $ϵ$ with $0 \lt ϵ \lt 1$, what is the probability that $X_n$ differs from $0$ by more than $ϵ$?
- What happens to that probability as $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the hint. This is what I got! Could you let me know if my proof is sufficient? So I know I need to show $P(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon) = 0$ for any positive $\epsilon$. Then, noting that $X_n$ follows a Bernoulli Distribution, $X_n$ can only take on non-negative integer values, so $P(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon)$ reduces to $P(X_n  > \epsilon)$. Here, I make use of Markov's Inequality, so $P(X_n  > \epsilon) \leq \frac 1\epsilon E(X_n)$ = $\frac 1\epsilon \frac 1n$. Then as $n$ tends to infinity, I can clearly see that the RHS tends to $0$.

Comment: @EthanMark I think you have, more or less, the right idea. Edit your question above giving your full proof. An intuituve understanding won't be enough for your lecturer.

Comment: @EthanMark - it is simpler than that: in this case $P(|X_n -0| \gt \epsilon) \le P(X_n \not = 0)=\frac1n$ and $\frac1n \to 0$ as $n$ increases

Comment: @stuartstevenson Thank you for the encouragement! I will do so in a bit.

Comment: @Henry Could you tell me how you deduced $P(|X_n -0| \gt \epsilon) \le P(X_n \not = 0)$?

Comment: @EthanMark The probability that $X_n$ is more than $\epsilon$ away from $0$ cannot exceed the probability that $X_n$ is anything away from $0$ which is the probability that $X_n$ is not equal to $0$.  If $0 \lt \epsilon \lt 1$ then here  $P(|X_n -0| \gt \epsilon) = P(X_n \not = 0)$

Comment: @Henry Oh wow. That is indeed much more elegant and faster than what I proposed. I would never have been able to see that. I know my method works, but thank you for letting me see an alternative!